# modeling entity relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a one to many relationship for `EntityA` & `EntityB` with another entity, lets call it `DependentEntity`; Here `EntityAOrBId` in `DependentEntity` stores the keys for `EntityA` & `EntityB`.

Is this a good design or should I separate the foreign key relationship & have `EntityAId` and `EntityBId` columns instead of a generic `EntityAOrBId` column?

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
    public DependentEntity DependentEntity { get; set;}
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int EntityBId { get; set; }
}

public class DependentEntity
{
    public int DependentEntityId { get; set; }
    public int EntityAOrBId { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking into your design alone, I may say that :

1. I cannot tell if the property EntityAOrBId in DependentEntity class is actually EntityAId or EntityBId
2. Class EntityB seems like an independent class that may or may not have any relation with any classes
3. Class EntityA and class DependentEntity may have circular references between them

If that's what you really mean by this post, it's OK for me. However, if it's not exactly what you mean, it could be misleading.

I believe the best practice with defining classes is you need to make them self-explained classes.

So, if it's me, I would go with plain classes like these, to abstract one to many relationships :

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DependentEntity> DependentEntity { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int EntityBId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DependentEntity> DependentEntity { get; set; }
}
```

as also mentioned in the EF tutorial below :

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

Just to share my thoughts.

**EDITED :**

Based on your inquiry and the EF tutorial above, let's see if we have more options to consider :

**CASE #1** : If one DependentEntityId can be shared among Entity A and B, the class would be like this :

```
public class DependentEntity
{
    public int DependentEntityId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntityAId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntityBId { get; set; }
}
```

**CASE #2** : But if there's only either A or B, the class might be the one you have proposed already :

```
public class DependentEntity
{
    public int DependentEntityId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntityAOrBId { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
}
```

**CASE #3 :** I don't know what kind of entities we are talking about, but if entity A and B are actually the same kind of entity, I would go with this design :

```
public class EntityAOrB
{
    public int EntityAOrBId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DependentEntity> DependentEntity { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
}

public class DependentEntity
{
    public int DependentEntityId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntityAOrBId { get; set; }
}
```

Again, it's depend on your cases. But for me it's important that you can get the abstraction of your own application only by looking into the construction of your classes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: my apologies, I forgot to include entity type. I have entity type property in the dependent entity,

Comment: I'm sorry but my answer will still remain the same, because abstraction is the most important thing for me when designing classes.

Comment: How would you define the foreign key relationship? As it is shared between a and b

Answer (score 0):

You can have it both ways. Ea or Eb, Ea AND Eb.

It really depends on what your data is actually going to look like, AND for what purpose.

Certainly you cannot have the same value for both Ea and Eb, as that will break independence, and you won't be able to tell which is which.

If there are going to be the same values for both Ea and Eb, but that value is in reference to two different things, then I would not use the above design. I would therefore create two separate columns.

It's probably better you do actually separate them, as the cost is minimal and if data corruption/entry errors, occur, you'll be able to see which of the two columns has the issue.

Try this..

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
    public DependentEntity DependentEntity { get; set;}
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int EntityBId { get; set; }
    public DependentEntity DependentEntity { get; set;}
}

public class DependentEntity
{
    public int DependentEntityId { get; set; }
    public ...etc..etc
}
```

I hope that helped.

Comment: the classes are in one to one relationship in your code. Shouldn't it be one to many as asked by OP..?

Comment: @AbdulHameed: Not necessarily. Both Ea or Eb can have many DependentEntity records, with the same ID. That's ONE to MANY. If DependentEntity had both Ea and Eb as separate columns then yes that would be ONE to ONE.

Comment: my apologies, I forgot to include entity type. I have entity type property in the dependent entity,